# Syncing file and folder from a live website to a GitHub pages repository

Tags: github, command, line

I have:

- created a simple portfolio with a third party website content creator;
- I put the html code into a brand new GitHub Pages repository, so I've create a simple copy that's seems work fine.

Now I'd like to know how do I do to syncing and update the files and folder of the Github Pages repository every time I make a change onto the live website.
Is there a command line tools?

Answer (score 0):

The normal update workflow for a GitHub page site is:

- you modify your pages in your local cloned repository, with your third party website content creator
- add, commit and push
- wait a few second and refresh the page: your changes should be there.